# Try-Except exceptions creating more exceptions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm still learning python, so humor me. I'm making a text adventure as a way to learn and I'm trying to implement a way for the player to respond to a prompt given a list of things to "interact" with (returning a string from a nested dictionary). I'm trying to make the program print the value of "self.location["interper"]".

Here's the bit of code that's giving me issues.

```
# give the player the ability to "talk" and touch things

    # if there is nothing to interact with, say that there is nothing
    if "interobj" not in self.location and "interper" not in self.location:
        dismiss_fx.play()
        print("There's nothing of interest here.")

    # proceed if there is
    else:
        # print the things that are in the room
        confirm_fx.play()
        print("In the area, these things stand out to " + self.name + ": ")
        if "interobj" in self.location:
            print(colorama.Fore.YELLOW + colorama.Style.BRIGHT + self.location["interobj"])
        if "interper" in self.location:
            print(colorama.Fore.YELLOW + colorama.Style.BRIGHT + self.location["interper"])

        # prompt the user to interact with one of the things    
        interaction = input(colorama.Fore.CYAN + colorama.Style.BRIGHT + "\nWhich do you want " + self.name + " to interact with?: ")

        # determine if the thing the user interacted with is in the location
        try:
            raise KeyError(interaction)

        except KeyError as e:
            if str(e) != self.location["interobj"]:
                raise 

            elif interaction == self.location["interobj"]:
                # return whatever was noteworthy about the object
                confirm_fx.play()
                print(colorama.Fore.YELLOW + colorama.Style.BRIGHT + self.location["intercom"])
                print("")

            checkprog(self,interaction)

        except KeyError as e:
            if str(e) != self.location["interper"]:
                raise

            elif interaction == self.location["interper"]:
                # return whatever the character had to say
                confirm_fx.play()
                print(colorama.Fore.YELLOW + colorama.Style.BRIGHT + self.location["intersay"])
                print("")

            checkprog(self,interaction)

        except KeyError:
            # input is invalid
            invalid_fx.play()
            print(self.name + " couldn't find a '" + interaction + "'.")
            print("")
```

What this is supposed to do is:

1. Prompt the user for input if there's a key called "interper" or "interobj".
2. Interpret the input and determine if the input is the value of an "interper" or "interobj" key.
3. If the input is the value of one of those two keys, it prints the value of the keys "intersay" or "intercom", for "interper" and "interobj", respectively.
4. If it is neither of those values, it returns a message saying the input was invalid.

In actuality, it just tells me that the way I handled the exceptions is creating more exceptions.

TL;DR: Can someone explain exception handling in a way that's easy to understand? I don't understand the "raise" function.

If you can help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: The `raise` function *raises an exception.*  So what you're doing is catching an exception, but then immediately throwing a new one.  What you should probably do instead in your exception handler (the `except` block) is *handle the exception you just caught.*

Comment: You should also probably limit the amount of conditional checking in your exception handlers.  If you catch an exception, you should already have a pretty good idea why the error occurred without doing conditional checking that risks further exception throws.

Comment: If it helps, think of exception handling as a pitcher and a catcher.  In other languages, this metaphor is more easily seen because exceptions are `throw`n when an error occurs, and a `catch` block catches them.  The benefit of this arrangement is that the "catcher" can be located anywhere in your upstream call stack.  If you can't handle the exception locally, you just let it walk up the call stack until it either finds a handler, or the program exits with an error.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `try:` block, you are checking to see if the code inside the block raises an exception (has an error). If there is an exception, the interpreter immediately jumps to the except block and executes the code there. If there is no exception, then the interpreter simply executes the code in the `try:` block and then moves to the line following the `except` block. When you call `raise` inside the try block, you are making it so that even if your code works, an exception will be 'raised', because the raise function automatically raises an exception. You want to just put your normal code inside the try block without raise, and if there is an exception it will handle it in the except block.